# X509Certificate - How to set validation Policies?

Tags: .net, cryptography, x509certificate, bouncycastle, pki

EDIT: I am using .Net/C# environment for development & Bouncy Castle for all cryptography operations. Looking for a solution/suggestion which could be implemented with Bouncy Castle itself.

I have an X509Certificate (say Certificate-A) for signing purpose. While validating this certificate, I have to check its path with Intermediate & Root certificate which I have implemented fully.

There is a custom extension in this Certificate-A which has a another signature as its value. While validating this Certificate-A, I am taking the signature from it's custom extension & do verify it with another Certificate-B that produced it. This all is being done well.

Now is there a way to add some Policy to Certificate-A by which a third party validator comes to know by reading this Policy (ONLY) that it has to take signature from Certificate-A & verify with Certificate-B?

Note- Certificate-A & B would be already available to third party validator (Certificate List in a PKCS#7 Signature).

Comment: Are you sure this is a programming-related question? Unless you specify an exact software framework you want to implement this in, [security.stackexchange.com](http://security.stackexchange.com) seems a better place to get help with your issue.

Comment: @AntonSamsonov Yes this is programming related question only. I've edited the question as you suggested. I wanted to know first if it was the standard approach (i believe it should be) to do this. If some standard method is there, Bouncy Castle should be having it.

Comment: Please first have a look at [cross signed certificates](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14043/what-is-the-use-of-cross-signing-certificates-in-x-509) and see if that leads to a solution to your problem. I don't think this is a programming question *yet*. I think you need to split the protocol part and the implementation part, and go to security for the protocol part.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the question relies on an answer about the protocol to use. Try http://security.stackexchange.com instead.